# Prevent Phonegap notification.navigator popups from closing from touch outside of dialog

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, cordova

I am using Phonegap to build an Android application and am running into problems using functionality that is not well documented for Phonegap.

```
navigator.notification.activityStart('title', 'message');
```

The above works fine, and using it with `activityStop()` opens and closes the loading dialog when I need it to. The problem is that if the user touches the screen or hits the back button the loading dialog closes. I want it to remain open until I am done loading a document from a server in the background.

I am running into the same problem with `navigator.notification.alert` and the other functions of the `navigator.notification`.

Also, I would prefer to not modify any native code. I know that I could probably edit the Phonegap plugin native code to achieve this, but this application will eventually be cross-platform so I would prefer to not do any native code if possible.

Comment: I edited the native code for the Phonegap plugin to fix this for the time being, but am still looking for a solution that is easier. The most simple way to do this is to edit the `activityStart()` method to match `progressStart()` so you can then apply the properties `setCancelable(false)` and `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`.

Comment: hi, can you post the example out?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which I integrated in my application and it worked.

In java file of notification alert do the following change :

=> go to alert ()
=> dlg.setCancelable(false);

Good luck